# awk memory leak?

Tags: awk, osx, memory

Base on [this](http://blog.robertelder.org/bash-one-liner-compose-music/) I'm running the command

```
< /dev/urandom hexdump -v -e '/1 "%u\n"' |
awk '{ split("0,2,4,5,7,9,11,12",a,",");
       for (i = 0; i < 1; i+= 0.0001)
         printf("%08X\n", 100*sin(1382*exp((a[$1 % 8]/12)*log(2))*i)) }' |
xxd -r -p |
sox -traw -r44100 -b16 -e unsigned-integer - -tcoreaudio
```

I notice that the memory used by awk continually grows while this command is running, for example consuming over 500MB of memory by the time 75MB of raw audio data has been played. All of the other commands in the pipeline maintain a constant amount of memory.

What is awk using this memory for and is there an alternative that does the intended stream processing using only a constant amount of memory?

---

in case the awk version matters:

```
⑆ awk --version
awk version 20070501
```

---

Here's the command I tested based on Thomas Dickey's answer:

```
< /dev/urandom hexdump -v -e '/1 "%u\n"' |
awk 'BEGIN { split("0,2,4,5,7,9,11,12",a,",") }
           { for (i = 0; i < 1; i+= 0.0001)
               printf("%08X\n", 100*sin(1382*exp((a[$1 % 8]/12)*log(2))*i)) }' |
xxd -r -p |
sox -traw -r44100 -b16 -e unsigned-integer - -tcoreaudio
```

Comment: I also see a memory leak on my BSD-Darwin (Mac) system.

Comment: You said `Here's the command I tested...` but you forgot to tell us the result of that testing - did it solve the problem or not? It may not since every reference to an element in `a[]` in the loop would create entries if they didn't exist so if it doesn't - does it help if you explicitly delete the array before splitting or after using it, e.g. `awk '{ delete a; split("0,2,4,5,7,9,11,12",a,","); for (i = 0; i < 1; i+= 0.0001) printf("%08X\n", 100*sin(1382*exp((a[$1 % 8]/12)*log(2))*i)) }'`? With that code segment you need to leave the split() in it's original location, not move it to BEGIN.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This statement is odd:

```
split("0,2,4,5,7,9,11,12",a,",");
```

It repetitively splits a constant string to create an array `a`.  If you move that into a `BEGIN` section, the program should work the same — without allocating a new copy of the `a` array for each input-record.

Addressing comments: the for-loop and expression do not allocate memory in a simple manner.  A quick comparison of mawk, gawk and awk shows that there is no problem with the first two, but `/usr/bin/awk` on OSX does leak rapidly.  If Apple had a bug-reporting system, that would be the place to go.

Comment: I did as you suggested on my Mac (I'm not the OP). I still see a memory leak with awk.

Comment: Somehow, simply _referencing_ the **a** hash uses memory.

Comment: Same here; I still see the memory growth. I also did a rough comparison and the memory usage seems to be growing at the same rate with this change.

Comment: Even this will cause a memory leak: `awk 'BEGIN { split("0,2,4,5,7,9,11,12",a,","); } { for (i = 0; i < 1; i+= 0.0001) a[1]; }'`

Comment: You could switch to mawk or gawk.  Apple's base system includes some real antiques.

Comment: Yep, switching to gawk fixes the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Otheus This doesn't *need to be* a memory leak -- it's simply consuming much memory. It'd be a memory-leak if the memory allocated isn't used/freed but that's difficult to determine. It's excessive memory allocation

Comment: @larkey. No, it was a memory leak in the sense that the program was allocating increasing amounts of memory for every iteration / line of input. This was easy to determine.

Comment: @Otheus This is no memory leak. Eg. if you do anything recursively and allocate on each step and free afterwards you continuously allocate memory too -- but no memory leak. I don't know how awk works internally: It might be a memory leak but it might not.

Comment: @larkey dude, I can see the memory usage increasing simply by referencing the array inside an awk "program". There is no recursion. It matters not if there's a loop or if there's a complicated expression: only the array reference.

Comment: Since `awk` does automatic memory management (i.e. garbage collection), the fact that it's not collecting memory that's clearly become garbage means there's a leak in the implementation.

Comment: @Otheus wrt `I can see the memory usage increasing simply by referencing the array` - yes you would because by design in awk referencing an array index creates that array element if it didn't previously exist. So if `a["foo"]` didn't exist then using `a["foo"]` in your code would create `a["foo"] = zero-or-null`. To test whether foo was already present and so avoid that happening you'd use `if ("foo" in a)`.

Comment: @EdMorton If it were because of _design_ the different implementations would not differ w.r.t memory usage. Also, in my dummy example in a previous comment, I'm not referencing anonymous array entries, but fixed ones.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a perl equivalent that doesn't leak:

```
perl -lne 'BEGIN { @a=(0,2,4,5,7,9,11,12);}
   for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i+= 0.0001) {
     printf("%08X\n", 100*sin(1382*exp($a[$F[0] % 8]/12)*log(2))*$i) }'
```

It's almost identical. `$1` gets replaced by `$F[0]` and `i` is replaced with `$i`. The hash `a` is replaced with an actual array, `@a`.

You would be wise to generate some input and compare the output and note differences between the two. There are often nuances as to how interpretive languages deal with floating point.